# Is it legal to create a website that freely provides the contents of books which are another company's IP?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

This question is rather specific. I am a fan of the tabletop roleplaying game 'Call of Cthulhu' by Chaosium Inc., but find since it isn't hugely popular that there aren't enough easily accessible online resources for the game. 
I want to create a website which serves as an electronic resource for finding the information strewn throughout Chaosium's many source books for the game.

Would it be legal for me to do so?
My best reference for this is a very similar website for Dungeons and Dragons, [5etools](https://5e.tools), which has almost all the content from all of Wizard of the Coast's books freely available on it. Is this not plagiarism? Piracy? It doesn't quite feel fully legal to me.

 
Thanks!

Comment: "It doesn't quite feel fully legal to me." Ah, it's not. It's just that no one has sued 5etools yet.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks

Comment: You might want to check if the 5etools uses the WotC Open Game License material only.

Comment: It definitely does uses more than OGL/SRD material, I was aware of this which is why I wanted to ask the question - it has word-for-word copies of most of the WotC published 5e modules.
I wouldn't be looking to do this with Call of Cthulhu ofc, instead I'd be wanting to include content from the main source books (Keeper's and Investigator's Handbooks) for use as reference, but from the other answers it seems that indeed this would still be illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot legally publish someone else's materials on a website.

It is no different from publishing a copy of a book for profit.